# REST API get call with credentials

Tags: javascript, api, sharepoint, xmlhttprequest

I have trying to call ServiceNow API from a SharePoint hosted adding i'm working on using JavaScript with credential for the header. But when i try to run it during the run time the request gets an error. Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.open('GET',Servicenow_URL, true);
req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

req.open("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(Username + ":" + password));
req.withCredentials = true;
req.send();
alert("here1");

if (req.readyState === 4) {
    if (req.status === 200) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
        alert("here2");
    } else {
        console.error(req.statusText);
        alert("error");
    }
}
```

the developer tool from browser shows the error as  "the server responded with a status of 501"

Comment: `Authorization` path has to be in your domain or you  need CORS access.

Comment: Use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45971776/edit to edit/update the question and paste in the exact error message the browser is logging in the browser devtools console

Comment: Using XMLHttpRequest is pretty clunky - you might find it easier using fetch() or some library.